# Is it possible to give a person an allergic reaction in a very specific place?

Tags: human-biology, cell-biology, immunology

Can I give a person an allergic reaction at a very specific spot in a tissue?
And if so, how accurate can i get?

Comment: You might want to look at the [patch test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Patch_test_(medicine)).  Though I'm a little concerned by the motivation of this question.

Comment: Thank you this did help :)
Lets say I know a persons allergic reactions will it be possible to do the following? and if so can I change the hypersensitivity level reaction in this proses?

Comment: I don't have enough information to make a full answer, but I'm allergic to mangoes. When I eat one, the parts of my skin that the mango touched will get a bad rash, but anywhere it didn't touch will be unaffected.

Answer (score 3):

Depends on the kind of allergic reactions you want to create. If your target tissue is skin [epithelium](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epithelium) sure you can.

That's actually the way the [skin allergy test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skin_allergy_test) is all about: The physician tries a wide variety - *last time I did it were 28 well known kinds* - of substances in liquid form (drops). If an allergic reaction is caused, the physician takes note. Even very small quantities can cause allergic reactions.

These tests are usually made in a secured environment (physician's office, hospital, etc) at a very low level which most of the times, if result is positive will cause just an irritation. The level of irritation will be self-explanatory, so even a non trained patient can understand what is going on.

Not sure if *that* what you were asking though.

Best Regards,

pa

Comment: Funnily, the severity of the reaction does not correlate to symptoms the allergy might cause... of all allergies I have, dust mites gave the weakest skin prick reaction; but it's the only symptomatic allergy I have. The prick test can vary a lot, depending on the purpose; I don't think there's a standard set of allergens they test, apart from ready-made allergen "sets" such as "grasses" or "trees".

Comment: Well, yeah I was referring to allergies about trees, grasses, dust, etc.  But sure, allergies are not 100% understood anyway.

Comment: Thank you this did help :) Lets say I know a persons allergic reactions will it be possible to do the following? and if so can I change the hypersensitivity level reaction in this proses?

Comment: You say "do the following", but there's no "following" sentence, so I don't know what you mean by "do the following". :-) - The hs reaction usually is "linear" but might have more than one variables, so I'd say that it's kind of dangerous to try it out on your own... Better visit a physician.

Comment: as in following i mean the patch test mentioned earlier :)
and i wont this is a part of sum recerch Im douing ill go to the universality to figer out more soon thank you.